# IConnectionPoint event in local server COM

Tags: com

I created a local server (EXE) COM project with support for ConnectionPoint events.

idl pseudo:

```
interface IAtlClass : IDispatch{
    [id(1)] HRESULT f1();
};
library ComExeLib
{
    dispinterface _IAtlClassEvents
    {
        methods:
            [id(1)] HRESULT f2();
    };
    [
        uuid(...
    ]
    coclass AtlClass
    {
        [default] interface IAtlClass;
        [default, source] dispinterface _IAtlClassEvents;
};
```

};

Server is built in **32 bit** configuration. Client code, built in **64 bit**:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

IAtlClass* atlClass;
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AtlClass, NULL,
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
    IID_IAtlClass,
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&atlClass));

hr = atlClass->f1();
IConnectionPointContainer* pICPC = NULL;
hr = atlClass->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (VOID **)&pICPC);
IConnectionPoint* pICP = NULL;
hr = pICPC->FindConnectionPoint(DIID__IAtlClassEvents, &pICP);
hr = pICP->Advise((_IAtlClassEvents*)&sink, &cookie);
```

Sink class:

```
class Sink : public _IAtlClassEvents
{
public:
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(
        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [iid_is][out] */ void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject)
    {
        if ((DIID__IAtlClassEvents == riid))
        {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<_IAtlClassEvents*>(this);
            AddRef();
            return(S_OK);
        }

        *ppvObject = NULL;
        return(E_NOINTERFACE);
    }

    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef(void)
    {
        return(InterlockedIncrement(&m_iRef));
    }
    ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release(void)
    {
        if (0 == InterlockedDecrement(&m_iRef))
        {
            delete this;
            return(0);
        }
        return(m_iRef);
    }
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfoCount()
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetTypeInfo()
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetIDsOfNames()
    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Invoke()
};
```

Registered the server with `ComExe.exe /RegServer` and the proxy with `regsvr32 ComExePS.dll`, under folder `C:\windows\SysWOW\` and under `c:\Windows\System32`.

Not sure if necessary but tried to compile the proxy stub under 64 bit as well but it will not build since auto-generated ComExe_p.c contains an `#if !defined(AMD64)..` so the project can only be built in 32 bit (seems related to [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d8f34ac-5a4c-416f-864a-c747c68e2d7f/vs2010-bug-unresolved-external-symbol-proxyfileinfo?forum=vcmfcatl) only I use VS2013).

All client code commands except the last (Advise) **succeed** (They succeed even without registering the `ComExePS.dll`) . Advise invokes the sink `QueryInterface` method (and none but it), five time with following iid's:

```
{00000003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
{ECC8691B-C1DB-4DC0-855E-65F6C551AF49}
{00000003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
{0000001B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
{IID_IUnknown}
```

None of which are related to `IAtlClass` (some standard MS iid's - [this guy was getting something similar](https://forum.dlang.org/post/vjemyrveqfmvwccejxuz@forum.dlang.org)).

Eventually `Advise` returns `E_UNEXPECTED Catastrophic failure` and the question is what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `_IAtlClassEvents::QueryInterface` implementation should support at least `IUnknown`, and likely also `IDispatch`.

Comment: What if the component supports more than one event interface (`IAtlClassEvents2`)?

Comment: You need a separate sink for each. Anyway, you are using ATL - why are you reinventing the wheel rather than using the mechanisms ATL specifically provides for this purpose? See [`IDispEventImpl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/idispeventimpl-class) - it's designed so a class can inherit from it more than once, each instance handling one event interface. See also: [Using `IDispEventImpl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/using-idispeventimpl)

Comment: When server calls `f2()` client gets `RPC_E_SERVERFAULT` (server `catch (...)` not hit)

Comment: What do you mean "client gets"? Gets where and how? Which call, exactly, returns `RPC_E_SERVERFAULT`?

Comment: Say, client calls `f1()`. `f1` raises the `f2` event, so you would expect the `sink.f2` to be invoked. But when server calls `p_IAtlClassEvents->f2()` `f1` returns with `RPC_E_SERVERFAULT`. (you get `p_IAtlClassEvents` from casting `CProxy_IAtlClassEvents::m_vec.GetAt`)

Comment: `_IAtlClassEvents` is a dispinterface. Its methods would be called via `Invoke`. `p_IAtlClassEvents->f2()` should not compile.

Comment: `RPC_E_SERVERFAULT` means the server crashed, essentially. Perhaps you didn't manage to advise the sink successfully after all, but the server doesn't check for that. E.g. `GetAt` would assert in debug build on an index out of bounds, and return `NULL` in release builds. Anyway, since you haven't shown the server code - the code that crashes - I can only guess.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for the assistance. Can you point to a complete example of using events in local server COM? Seems I'm struggling with issue that should be common/standard.

Comment: [ATL tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/active-template-library-atl-tutorial) has a section on events. [DispSink sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/VCSamples/tree/master/VC2010Samples/ATL/General/DispSink). [ATLDuck sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/VCSamples/tree/master/VC2010Samples/ATL/Advanced/ATLDuck). [connect sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/VCSamples/tree/master/VC2010Samples/ATL/Advanced/connect)