# Implementing unknown Interfaces in COM local exe server

Tags: c++, winapi, com

Before i present the problem [here](https://github.com/SyncIt21/COMBasicsMRE)  is the link to the full project source code. Its a solution with 3 projects under it(overall 55kb in size) and requires Visual studio 2022

1. COMBasics - This is the actual COM client you need to run
2. COMServer - The COM server which serves objects to the COM Client
3. SampleInterfaces - a static library project which contains all the interfaces used by the client & implemented by the server i.e shared source code between client & server

**To prep the projects to build & compile**

a) Open visual studio and open the COMBasics solution file

b) Go to properties of COMBasics
-> C/C++
-> General
->Additional Include Directories and add the directory where the source files for
SampleInterfaces project is located

c) Do the same for COMServer

**Finaly to launch the projects**

First launch the COMServer in debug mode by

1. Right Click
2. Debug
3. Start New Instance

Then open the solution explorer and do the same for the COMBasics project(Client). If everything is successful when you launch the Client you will get the console output

```
Interface not supported
```

Twice in the console which is why i'm here to solve this problem

The project source code is small but if i were to paste all of it in this question it would throw people off which is why i'm going to focus only on the few source files that actually matter to this problem

```
Interface not supported
```

**The Problem**

It's an exact duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626790/iconnectionpoint-event-in-local-server-com) literarly nothing different about it at all from mine. Since no solution was posted i read the comments.

They suggested to implement [IDispatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch) and i did. Now i did not know how to implement the methods of this interface so i read this [article](https://www.thrysoee.dk/InsideCOM+/ch05c.htm) and it answered all my problems. I did not use any IDL files because i wanted to learn about creating dynamic IDL files. So this is what i did.

If you have learnt the source code My plan is to delegate the methods of `IMouse` and `IKeyboard` to the actual implementations objects inside Computer so i first created 4 methods in COMServer->TestImplementations.h

```
virtual HRESULT click(int button);
virtual HRESULT scroll(int amount);
virtual HRESULT pressKey(int key);
virtual HRESULT releaseKey(int key);
```

Then i created a dynamic TypeInfo & finally the IDispatch implementation which i will delegate all functions to

```
//virtual HRESULT click(int button);
  BSTR param1_name_1 = CStringW("button").AllocSysString();
  PARAMDATA param1 = { param1_name_1, VT_INT };
  PARAMDATA* params = { &param1 };
  BSTR method_name_1 = CStringW("click").AllocSysString();
  METHODDATA clickMethod = {
    method_name_1,
    params,
    100L,              //Unique ID for method
    0,                 //Index of method in header file
    CC_STDCALL,        //__stdcall convention
    1,                 //number of arguments
    DISPATCH_METHOD,   //this is a method
    VT_HRESULT         //return type is HRESULT
  };


  //virtual HRESULT scroll(int amount);
  BSTR param1_name_2 = CStringW("amount").AllocSysString();
  param1 = { param1_name_2, VT_INT };
  params = { &param1 };
  BSTR method_name_2 = CStringW("scroll").AllocSysString();
  METHODDATA scrollMethod = {
    method_name_2,
    params,
    101L,              //Unique ID for method
    1,                 //Index of method in header file
    CC_STDCALL,        //__stdcall convention
    1,                 //number of arguments
    DISPATCH_METHOD,   //this is a method
    VT_HRESULT         //return type is HRESULT
  };

 
  //virtual HRESULT pressKey(int key);
  BSTR param1_name_3 = CStringW("key").AllocSysString();
  param1 = { param1_name_2, VT_INT };
  params = { &param1 };
  BSTR method_name_3 = CStringW("pressKey").AllocSysString();
  METHODDATA pressMethod = {
    method_name_3,
    params,
    102L,              //Unique ID for method
    2,                 //Index of method in header file
    CC_STDCALL,        //__stdcall convention
    1,                 //number of arguments
    DISPATCH_METHOD,   //this is a method
    VT_HRESULT         //return type is HRESULT
  };

  //virtual HRESULT releaseKey(int key);
  BSTR param1_name_4 = CStringW("key").AllocSysString();
  param1 = { param1_name_4, VT_INT };
  params = { &param1 };
  BSTR method_name_4 = CStringW("releaseKey").AllocSysString();
  METHODDATA releaseMethod = {
    method_name_4,
    params,
    103L,              //Unique ID for method
    3,                 //Index of method in header file
    CC_STDCALL,        //__stdcall convention
    1,                 //number of arguments
    DISPATCH_METHOD,   //this is a method
    VT_HRESULT        //return type is HRESULT
  };

  //Create the ITypeInfo or the equivalent IDL file
  METHODDATA methods[] = { clickMethod, scrollMethod, pressMethod, releaseMethod };
  INTERFACEDATA iData = { methods, 4 };
  HRESULT hr = CreateDispTypeInfo(
    &iData,
    LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
    &typeInfo
  );
  SysReleaseString(param1_name_1);
  SysReleaseString(param1_name_2);
  SysReleaseString(param1_name_3);
  SysReleaseString(param1_name_4);
  SysReleaseString(method_name_1);
  SysReleaseString(method_name_2);
  SysReleaseString(method_name_3);
  SysReleaseString(method_name_4);
  if (FAILED(hr)) { return; }

  //Create the IDispatch Implementation which we will delegate to
  hr = CreateStdDispatch(
    this,
    this,
    typeInfo,
    &dispatch
  );
  if (FAILED(hr)) { dispatch = nullptr; }
```

The IDispatch implementation

```
IUnknown* dispatch
```

Was created successfully and now whenever COM asks me for this interface i simply handover this implementation in `Computer::QueryInterface()` as follows

```
HRESULT __stdcall Computer::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject)
{
  if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
    *ppvObject = (IUnknown*)this;
  else if (riid == IID_IMOUSE)
    *ppvObject = (IMouse*)&mouse_implementation;
  else if (riid == IID_IKEYBOARD)
    *ppvObject = (IKeyboard*)&keyboard_implementation;
  else if (riid == IID_IDispatch)  //Delegate IDispatch here
    return dispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, ppvObject);
  else
  {
    *ppvObject = NULL;
    return ResultFromScode(E_NOINTERFACE);
  }
   
  ((IUnknown*)*ppvObject)->AddRef();

  return S_OK;
}
```

So what's the problem? COM never asks me `IDispatch` so the whole delegation never gets executed. And if you debug Computer::QueryInterface and examine the `ruid` passed to it you will get these exact same values

```
{00000003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
{ECC8691B-C1DB-4DC0-855E-65F6C551AF49}
{00000003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
{0000001B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
{IID_IUnknown}
```

The comments suggested implementing `IDispatch` but the COM Client never asks for it. I return `E_NOIMPL` for everything which is why the final output is exactly that No Interface supported so what's next?
What other interfaces should i implement to make my COMServer return the computer object to the client so it can work?

I have tested this code in creating a `INPROC_SERVER(same process memory)` and everything works its only `LOCAL_SERVER` that i can't get to work.

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Sorry. Test the link now

Comment: `IMouse` and `IKeyboard` derive from IUnknown so COM doesn't know how to marshal them (across process here, but across thread wouldn't work well either). If you query for `IDispatch` in `local_process_create_Test` it will work because COM knows how to marshal `IDispatch`. There's a lot of (more complex than one thinks) boilerplate code that you're writing (sometimes incorrectly). You should use a framework such as Visual Studio ATL to write COM code, it's much easier (although you need to learn ATL, it's worth it, especially from C/C++). Also you must generate interfaces using MIDL

Comment: It is easy to generate an IDL file as Visual studio has an ATL project format for that , but i purposely avoided that because i wanted to create an TypeInterface[i.e. IDL] of of own using `CreateDispTypeInfo` proc so i could learn how it works. Regarding Marshalling that is a new term for me so i'm unfamiliar how to implement that in my code. Feel free to remove the boiler plate and restructure the code to create the smallest working example from it and i'll do the research from your answer because I've been stuck 2 days on this now so I'm unsure how to apply your suggestions

Comment: There are many ways to do this. First structural choice is do you want 1) IUnknown-derived ("early binding", easier from C/C++) or 2) pure IDispatch-derived ("late binding", easier for VB/VBA/Scripting/Python/.NET/etc.) or 3) "dual": IUnknown-derived + IDispatch implementation. For 1) and 3) I would use ATL with MIDL and TLB (follow ATL tutorials). For 2) just get rid of IKeyboard and IMouse and use IDispatch calls only (with IDispatch, it's better to use smart classes like CComBSTR/Variant or _com_bstr, etc). Entire books have been written on all this, try to read some :-)

Comment: I also forgot to say I'm fairly new to COM and this is a lot of information to process. If you can create the smallest working example with the preferred method of your choice from my code I'll mark it as answered. I just need a small push in the right direction by seeing some working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *IMouse* and *IKeyboard* interfaces derive from *IUnknown* so COM doesn't know how to marshal them.

It's difficult and tedious to write native C/C++ COM code w/o a framework, such as [ATL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/active-template-library-atl-concepts) (requires a Visual Studio license). There's lots of boilerplate code needed that's not super easy to come up with, expecially when you're new to COM.

Out-Of-Process COM is typically much more complex than In-Process (COM server in a dll) because it involves marshaling, proxying, etc.

There's an "official" sample of an ATL Out-Of-Process COM server here [Out-of-process ATL COM server (ATLExeCOMServer)](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/OneCodeTeam/Out-of-process%20ATL%20COM%20server%20(ATLExeCOMServer)) but it's kinda outdated, doesn't compile right away, and only uses [OLE-automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/automation) so doesn't demonstrate scenarios involving non OLE-automation interfaces.

So I’ve created another one here https://github.com/smourier/OutOfProcessCOMServer with a full readme with additional information. It also contains a C++ client, a .NET client and a VBScript client.

Main steps to follow:

- From Visual Studio create a new ATL project (and check "Allow merging of PS code":

[image]

Then add a new "Mouse" ATL Simple Object item:

[image]

Run "Finish" w/o changing anything:
[image]

Remove the auto registration (unless you run Visual Studio as admin):

[image]

Modify the idl for something like this:

[image]

Some important points;

- *IMouse* is a **dual** (*IDispatch* + *IUnknown-derived*) interface while *IKeyboard* is a simple *IUnknown-derived* interface. I've done that on purpose to be able to see the difference.
- So, *IMouse* doesn't need specific marshaling, doesn't need a proxy stub, because it's (automagically) done by OLE-automation plumbing. The generated TLB file contains metadata that fully describes *IMouse* and its methods and the system can build a proxy/stub dynamically.
- On the other hand, *IKeyboard* is not an OLE-automation interface and uses custom C-style arguments (like LPCWSTR). This is fully supported by COM but requires some RPC-plumbing. This plumbing is generated by MIDL for you (proxy/stub C code) but is useless in the exe project (not sure why ATL puts the file in there...). You need to register all this plumbing into the system to be able to use IKeyboard across threads, processes, machines.
- For that reason, I've created another project *OutOfProcessCOMServerPS* project from an empty DLL file:

[image]

When this proxy/stub dll is also registered, you can access *IKeyboard* from COM clients capable of accessing non OLE-automation interfaces (C/C++, .NET, Delphi, etc.)

If you only use dual interfaces (which restricts you to [OLE-automation data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/7b5fa59b-d8f6-4a47-9695-630d3c10363e)), then you don't need this custom PS dll.

Comment: Took me several hours to understand but i got there. While it's easy to get the IDE to do everything for you one one would get deeper understanding if they could manually implement what the IDE is doing behind the scenes like writing your own custom Marshaller and making your own RPC calls but yeah there is too much complexity under the hood so ill stick with this. Thank you for the effort

Comment: @Syncit - Note that "custom marshaling" is in fact one step deeper. Here we still have *standard* marshaling even with a proxy/stub (OLE-automation-based marshaling used to be called "universal marshaling" and Oleaut32.dll the "universal marshaler" since it only needs a tlb, not a dll or even nothing when sticking with IDispatch exclusively). *Custom* marshaling means you implement `IMarshal` (when asked for it). This is still possible but in general useless today. It was interesting back then to optimize bits during thread/process/machine transfer (for array of bytes/structs, for example).

Comment: Speaking of custom marshalling I did find this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15223/Understanding-Custom-Marshaling-Part-1) and I am also finding documentation atleast for making [local rpc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/proxy) calls so I might get somewhere with this. Thanks for giving me the push.