# Access read & write exceptions when executing custom COM client & server

Tags: c++, winapi, proxy, com, stub

This questions builds upon the code linked in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76821245/implementing-unknown-interfaces-in-com-local-exe-server) question

In my research for custom Marshalling i came across this [article](https://www.thrysoee.dk/InsideCOM+/ch15b.htm) and it gave me all the insight i needed to create my own Proxy/Stubb without the help of visual studio.

[here](https://github.com/SyncIt21/COMProxyStubMRE) is the link to the full project, follow the exact same instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76821245/implementing-unknown-interfaces-in-com-local-exe-server) question to get the server and client up & running

**So Whats the problem?**

First let me tell what isn't the problem

1. Proxy gets created client side
2. Stub gets created server side

Everything gets set up exactly as planned on both ends until errors randomly occur. When i say random i mean it,

1. Sometimes you get a write access violation exception
   [image]
2. Other times an execution violation exception
   [image]
3. And finally(i think) You get another exception over here
   [image]

I have been debugging this for over a day now and still can't pinpoint why these segments of code keep failing at random which is why I'm asking help here in debugging.

If anyone does manage to get this code working then the Com Client should communicate with COM server and you will see output like this on the client side

```
Click 1
Scroll 10
Key Pressed 5
Key Released 10
```

Basically the COM server sends these strings as char arrays from the STUB to the PROXY and the proxy finally prints the received values.

Comment: @Simon Mourier if your kind enough I could use your help once again

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Post your code as text. Preferably as a [mcve] that we can use to compile and run locally.

Comment: The code to run is present in this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k3UDthJRiiEWUADrlZmo2t74EkWnBo8f/view?usp=sharing) this is the MRE. I'm just showing what parts of the code fail as pictures

Comment: I suspect the issue is with your handrolled proxy/stub code. I've never seen anyone try to do this. Most of just let MIDL generate the proxy/stub code from an IDL file.  Your code would also benefit from more logging to keep track of the addref/release and object lifetime. It's possible you have a refcount issue you weren't aware of. But most of us just use ATL template instead of handrolling our own addref/release/qi implementations. Also, just CComPtr as a worthy smart pointer class.

Comment: In other words, you're doing way too much "COM 1995" style programming instead of leveraging ATL and MIDL to do the hard work for you.

Comment: [mcve] required. In the question itself.

Comment: I am aware of using visual studio to generate all the ATL boiler plate code and it works I have no problems there. I am deliberately trying to understand the low level workings of ATL by creating my stub/proxy. Regarding ref counting you are right on that,  some objects on watching have refcounts greater than 3 for some reason,  thanks I'll try debugging that further.

Comment: Standard marshaling using the generated proxy/stub is *not* a Visual Studio feature, it's provided by the Windows SDK (MIDL). Visual Studio (tooling and ATL) just simplifies this. The first problem you have is you *must* use (`AddRef` it at least, `Release` when finished) the `pUnkOuter` argument passed to CreateProxy. You can (should) also use it for any other public interfaces (not IMouse, not IKeyboard, not IRpcProxyBuffer) you would be asked for. I'd recommend to create 1 class (called "facelet", read "Inside OLE2" book) for IMouse+IRpcProxyBuffer and 1 class for IKeyBoard+IRpcProxyBuffer.

Comment: The project link in the question has been updated to point to my github repo so you can see the changes more transparently when you give suggestions. I took your suggestion to merge IKeyBoard+IRpcProxyBuffer into one class and same for the  IMouse+IRpcProxyBuffer. I also made sure to store and delegate unhandled `QueryInterface` to `pUnkOuter` as requested but now i have a different problem. both Mouse & Keyboard proxy buffers get immediately disconnected after connecting so i can't send any data to the stub.

Comment: Also some more good news. As soon as i delegated calls to `pUnkOuter` CoCreateInstance now succeeds every time so no more access read/write violations but `proxyBuffer` gets immediatly disconnected so it becomes null by the time i try to use it to send data.  I am not familiar with aggregation concepts so definitly i messed up something there in the `MouseProxyBuffer` & `KeyboardProxyBuffer` classes

Comment: Now, I'm not sure why you use CoRegisterPSClsid but instead you should create a PS dll and register it as explained in all documentation (ProxyStubClsid32 etc.). CoRegisterPSClsid is used in special cases and the doc talks about "in-process handler or in-process server", not out-of-process server and I don't think it's meant for both sides of the RPC channel.

Comment: Also your project on github doesn't compile, it's missing TestImplementation.cpp (at least)

Comment: Please read this again: [mcve]. Read it *thoroughly*. If you don't follow the instructions, your question will get closed. That's how Stack Overflow works. You don't get to decide which rules apply to your question.

Comment: I'm so sorry about the github project.  I added the file so it should all compile now.  I'm using CoRegisterPSClsid because I just learnt about the function so I wanted to see how it works. Yes the registry editing works too but right now I'm just exploring all options. Also regarding an MRE all the code is now on github and compiles. I have posted large amounts of code in questions in the past to make an MRE but everytime I did the question got downvoted because people got overwhelmed by large amounts of text so that's why I changed strategies.

Comment: You are right about in process handler so that's why I registered the IPCFactory in process once in my server and again in my client via CoRegisterPSClsid locally. I had registered an dll version of this in registry and it is the same outcome the dll is loaded twice locally first in client and then server to create the proxy & stub

Comment: The Connect+Disconnect w/o calling method probably means there's a reference counting issue on the proxy manager. Add an extra AddRef to check. Also none of your AddRef and Release are thread-safe, use InterlockedIn(De)crement. As for the 2 dlls, yes it's expected, but it shouldn't be the same result. Currently you get RPC_E_INVALID_HEADER 0x80010111 messages in Debug output which may go away if you stop using CoRegisterPSClsid

Comment: It was past midnight yesterday, a new day now. So good news & bad news. bad news is `CoRegisterPSClsid` does not affect the output. I created a dll version by exporting all the `DLLGetClassObject` and other important function implementations and it didn't make any difference. The good news is the proxy & server no longer get immediatly disconnected, This was happening because i wasn't delegating `AddRef()` & `Release` to `pUnkOuter` and now all ref counts are correct, github repo has been upated and the connection is stable no more null pointer,read & write exceptions all of that is gone

Comment: The bad news is you are right i am also getting `RPC_E_INVALID_HEADER 0x80010111`. This might be because i am not structuring all the params of `RPCOLEMESSAGE` properly. Thanks for all the suggestions so far. I now don't get any runtime errors, now i have only  `RPC_E_INVALID_HEADER 0x80010111` problem

Comment: I may be missing something but the repo doesn't seem updated

Comment: The Repo is updated. The last commit is called "Aggregation" where i delegate `AddRef` & `Release` to `pUnkOuter`. While yes the invalid header error continues to occur before & after this commit the runtime errors were solved because of this commit

Comment: The invalid header error occurs when i attempt to send the packet at this [line](https://github.com/SyncIt21/COMProxyStubMRE/blob/5448041616a0ac6b4069c1abaac88f8cc5cf111c/SampleInterfaces/TestProxyBuffer.cpp#L102).

Comment: There's no Proxy/Stub project in the repo.

Comment: The Proxy & Stub is created by `TestIPCFactoryBuffer.cpp` in the SampleInterfaces project. It's not registered as a dll this is an in memory dynamic proxy & stub registered via `CoRegisterPSClsid` in client & server

Comment: That's not good, you must register a PS dll for the system to work. CoRegisterPSClsid is for clients only.

Comment: New project called `COMProxyStubMemory` which contains the proxy & stub code is added to repo. This is a very scaled down minimalistic version of the original ATL project which contains only the dll code and def file to export the dll functions such as `DllGetClassObject` which simply returns the `COMIPSFactoryBuffer` already present in `SampleInterfaces` project. The instructions to register the dll of this project which i used(which i think are correct) is present in the `RegistryInstructions.txt` file. I now get runtime errors in the server when using this dll

Comment: First problem is  this is wrong: https://github.com/SyncIt21/COMProxyStubMRE/blob/main/COMProxyStubMemory/dllmain.cpp#L6 should be `*ppv = NULL` and `QueryInterface(riid, (void**)ppv);`.

Comment: Took several hours but repo has been updated. Good news, I applied your suggestion and now the runtime errors are gone. Good catch. Also `COMProxyStubMemory.dll` built from the project can now be registered via `regsvr32.exe` so no need to manually set the registry entries. Bad news we are back to square 1 i.e. I still get the `INVALID HEADER` error. So now we know for sure regardless whether the proxy is loaded from an dll or via `CoRegisterPSCLSID` the invalid header error stays the same

Comment: It's going good overall i would say. With every suggestion you give i am resolving 1 error at a time. Thank you for the effort so far

Comment: inside `dllmain.cpp` make sure to change the path of `InProcServer32` to wherever you want the dll to be located i.e this [line](https://github.com/SyncIt21/COMProxyStubMRE/blob/ba90f7dc4f8c8907ac8a9c0bab227bcb4481ea05/COMProxyStubMemory/dllmain.cpp#L53) before building the dll & registering it

Comment: Invalid header error occurs once again in the same [line](https://github.com/SyncIt21/COMProxyStubMRE/blob/ba90f7dc4f8c8907ac8a9c0bab227bcb4481ea05/SampleInterfaces/TestProxyBuffer.cpp#L102). There must be a specific format we need to package the data before sending it, so far no luck finding what that is

Comment: Another issue is you must set `iMethod` (to >=3) (https://github.com/SyncIt21/COMProxyStubMRE/blob/main/SampleInterfaces/TestProxyBuffer.cpp#L98) *before* calling `GetBuffer` (https://github.com/SyncIt21/COMProxyStubMRE/blob/main/SampleInterfaces/TestProxyBuffer.cpp#L80) otherwise, the RPC layer thinks you're setting a buffer for calling iMethod 0 (which is always QueryInterface) which seems ok but will fail on SendReceive call of course..

Comment: Repo has been updated. ITS FINISHED!!. Everything works, no errors nothing output appears on console side, proxy & stub works all of it works HURRAY!!. Thank you so much for the hard work, If you can create an answer summarizing all the suggestions you put in the comments i will mark it as accepted and we will be done with this. In the future any COM related questions I'll make sure to Tag you first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that *Standard* marshaling using the generated RPC proxy/stub is not a Visual Studio feature, it's provided by the Windows SDK. [MIDL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/using-the-midl-compiler-2), the .IDL compiler is a SDK tool that generates the default P/S files (.c, .h, etc.), so it's really a Windows feature.

Visual Studio (general tooling, often used in conjunction with [ATL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/active-template-library-atl-concepts?view=msvc-170)) just simplifies this invoking MIDL for you.

Now, doing standard marshaling without the generated proxy/stub is still possible, but I wouln't recommend it, unless you have good reasons to do so. Reasons would include very specific optimisations in transferring arguments back & forth, that you know you can use, and you know the system can't. For example a specific type of parameter (like a string or a byte array) that the generated RPC code will transfer using big chunks of memory and you can transfer differently (like some shared handle to something internal to your specific context).

It now works in the repo mentioned, so let's go back to some glitches that had to be fixed:

- The first problem you had is one *must* use the `pUnkOuter` argument passed to the [IPSFactoryBuffer::CreateProxy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-ipsfactorybuffer-createproxy), so `AddRef` it at least, `Release` when finished.
- The `pUnkOuter` must also be delegated all `QueryInterface` calls for any other interface that *is not* `IRpcProxyBuffer` and that *is not* a proxied interface: `IMouse`, `IKeyboard`, etc.. (these must be implemented by the proxy implementor of course)
- If a [Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-irpcproxybuffer-connect) call is immediatly followed by a [Disconnect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-irpcproxybuffer-disconnect) call (proxy or stub), it means there's some reference count issue somewhere in your code which causes the system-provided proxy manager to consider it has to terminate the proxy/stub in question. This is what happens on proxy side if `pUnkOuter` is not used.
- On proxy side, when calling the [IRpcChannelBuffer::GetBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-irpcchannelbuffer-getbuffer), the [iMethod field of the RPCOLEMESSAGE struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/ns-objidl-rpcolemessage) *must* already be set to the method's vtable index (which must be >= 3 since a vtable always has at least the 3 IUnknown methods QueryInterface, AddRef, Release). If `iMethod` is set after the `GetBuffer` call, the stub's [IRpcStubBuffer::Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-irpcstubbuffer-invoke) will never be reached and the proxy will get an `RPC_E_INVALID_HEADER` error (0x80010111) in the `pStatus` out argument of the [SendReceive method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-irpcchannelbuffer-sendreceive). Note the "Inside COM+" book is wrong here (or maybe things have changed since but I doubt it).

Other remarks:

- It depends on context but you should make `AddRef` and `Release` implementations thread-safe, for example using [InterlockedIncrement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedincrement) and [InterlockedDecrement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockeddecrement) instead of `++` and `--` operators. Good practise, makes everyone's like easier.
- [IsIIDSupported method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-irpcstubbuffer-isiidsupported) implementation should `AddRef` when giving back an interface to the caller (as always with COM).